# Error: "System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services". How to Fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I get this error when i run my code

```
 Application startup exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddControllers' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.EnsureControllerServices(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at API.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__7_0(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in /Users/fathindosunmu/OneDrive/MyProjects/GitHubProjects/Reactivities/Reactivities/WebAPI/Startup.cs:line 168
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /Users/fathindosunmu/OneDrive/MyProjects/GitHubProjects/Reactivities/Reactivities/WebAPI/Startup.cs:line 166
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddControllers' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.EnsureControllerServices(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllers(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at API.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__7_0(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in /Users/fathindosunmu/OneDrive/MyProjects/GitHubProjects/Reactivities/Reactivities/WebAPI/Startup.cs:line 168
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at API.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in /Users/fathindosunmu/OneDrive/MyProjects/GitHubProjects/Reactivities/Reactivities/WebAPI/Startup.cs:line 166
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Although this is my `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("MsSqlConnection"));
            });
            
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsAllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                        builder.WithExposedHeaders("WWW-Authenticate");
                        builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                        builder.AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });

            services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler).Assembly);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(List.Handler));
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                
            }).AddFluentValidation(config=> 
                config.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Create>());
            
            
            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
            var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
            identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
            identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("IsActivityHost", policy =>
                {
                    policy.Requirements.Add(new IsHostRequirement());
                });
            });
            services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, IsHostRequirementHandler>();

            
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT:SigningKey"]));
            services.AddAuthorization();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).
                AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = key,
                        ValidateAudience= false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = context =>
                        {
                            //receiving jwt token as a request header from client because the chatHub is not a HTTP request
                            //Protocol
                            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/chat")))
                            {
                                context.Token = accessToken;
                            }

                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
            services.AddScoped<IJWTGenerator, JWTGenerator>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserAccessor, UserAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<IPhotoAccessor, PhotoAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<IProfileReader, ProfileReader>();
            services.Configure<CloudinarySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Cloudinary"));
        }
```

also, `program.cs` contains this

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

why does this error still persist when the required services have been added? and how can i fix it?

Comment: What does your `Program.cs` look like?

Answer (score 2):

The exception is thrown by [`EnsureControllerServices`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Builder/ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs#L508) when the service `MvcMarkerService` is missing. This happens in your `Startup.Configure` method when you call `.UseEndpoints`.

In `ConfigureServices` you call `.AddMvc` so I'm not sure why the exception is thrown. However, when creating an MVC web app in .NET Core 3.1 the recommendation is to call `.AddControllersWithViews` or [one of the other ways to register the MVC services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#mvc-service-registration). There is something amiss in how you register services in `Startup.ConfigureServices` and configure the pipeline in `Startup.Configure` you need to resolve.

Comment: The same error still persists and it is really weird. Please it would be nice to share my source code with you so you can take a look@Martin Liversage